# What resolution of Drawables i should use for this display metrics?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make my application to multiple screen support. so to achieve this i read the Android developers guildeline https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and i have created the different drawable and layout folders to put different size of images.

I tested the application in different devices and it looks fine in those devices, while i found that in one of 7" tablet the images are too small. to confirm this i created simple project and put same name of images in different folder and found that this device uses `ldpi` drawables and in generally the size of `ldpi` drawable used to be `36x36` and  that causes the issue, if i increase this drawable size then it will not compatible with other low-density devices.

Here is the [Dispaly Metrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) of the device in which i am having a problem.

```
{density=0.75, width=800, height=444, scaledDensity=0.75, xdpi=160.0, ydpi=160.42105}
```

How to deal with this problem ? if anyone have this issue before then please give me some advice. any idea and help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more control over this:

- [Specify multiple different images for different screen resolutions and densities.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) To do so read [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html). If you need even more precision in image scaling and quality you can use the fundamental size of screen attribute which is `sw<N>dp` - you can specify the smallest width of the screen where your image should be used. This is a qualifier name for a resource folder.

Some values you might use here for common screen sizes:

- 320, for devices with screen configurations such as:

  1. 240x320 ldpi (QVGA handset)
  2. 320x480 mdpi (handset)
  3. 480x800 hdpi (high density handset)
- 480, for screens such as 480x800 mdpi (tablet/handset).
- 600, for screens such as 600x1024 mdpi (7" tablet).
- 720, for screens such as 720x1280 mdpi (10" tablet).

**Just specify your device width and put your edited image that fits the best in corresponding `sw<N>dp` folder in your case `sw<444>dp`.**

You should also have a look at other [qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) that make Android choosing image at runtime (screen density, Available width, Available height, Screen size or Screen aspect). By combining these qualifiers and testing carefully you will be sure that the user has the best experience on each device.

**Shortly, put your image under drawable-sw<444>dp folder. (444-smaller screen metric)**

Comment: so what i need to create `drawable-sw800dp` for best fit drawable or `layout-sw800dp` folder to put best fit xml ?

Comment: drawable-sw800dp, because Android needs to know which image to use, not which layout. When the app starts android asks your app "Which image should I use?". With this folder you answer to Android: "Please use the image in folder drawable-sw800dp because my screen width is 800 or greater". Hope you got the point.

Comment: Don't forget also about screen density. You can specify different images for the same screen size but different densities like this `drawable-sw800dp-ldpi`, `drawable-sw800dp-mdpi` etc.

Comment: Thanks i need to check this out, with only `drawable-sw800dp` i got `ResourceNotfoundException`

Comment: You got it wrong. You shouldn't rename the existing folder, but add new for alternative resources. So there are many folders with different names. Android first looks for alternative resources in `drawable-<qualifier>` and if none are found uses image form `drawable` folder

Comment: i didn't renamed the folder but i just put images only in this folder other folders are empty to check if it uses that images or not

Comment: ah, I didn't see that your width is greater than height. The sw<N>dp is fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen area. So try sw<444>dp (smaller metric of the screen). This should work out.

Comment: ohh i see, Actually i am usinf selectors so in drawable i have lots of xmls and that images are in density specific folders.let me check with `drawable-sw444dp-ldpi` first

Comment: great, its working as expected. now i have small doubt would you like to explain me ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22515/discussion-between-taras-and-juned)